# VestaCP smtp not working. Cannot connect to Smtp server

Tags: php, linux, centos, smtp, vesta

I've set up a new vestacp on my server. I did a Wordpress installation but I get an error when wordpress tries to connect to smtp. I can mail to my gmail account via webmail, but I cannot send mail to my webmail account via gmail. Help.

```txt
2019-03-12 18:16:59 TLS error on connection from localhost (muhammetdemirel.com.tr) [127.0.0.1] (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file file=/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt): error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
2019-03-12 18:17:45 TLS error on connection from mail-oi1-f173.google.com [209.85.167.173] (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file file=/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt): error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
2019-03-12 18:18:45 TLS error on connection from mail-ot1-f41.google.com [209.85.210.41] (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file file=/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt): error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
2019-03-12 18:22:13 TLS error on connection from mail-oi1-f180.google.com [209.85.167.180] (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file file=/usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt): error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Let's Enscrypt for main domain of vps.
Please set owner permission for file as well.
Example:

```
chown -R root:mail /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.sv.abc.com.crt
chown -R root:mail /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.sv.abc.com.key
```

sv.abc.com is your main domain using for VPS